# How can memory be allocated to a macro?

Tags: c

For the below piece of code , I have defined a macro **abc** whose value has been redefined twice . When we run the code , the output is some garbage value , I am not getting how the macro is getting a garbage value when it is a macro and memory can't be allocated to a macro **abc** ?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define abc 10
    #define abc "rd"
    int main()
    {
    printf("%d",abc);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are using `%d` in your printf to print a string, namely `"rd"`.

Comment: redefining a macro remplaces the precedent value so you are displaying a pointer with %d that's why you are displaying random values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have define the same `abc` macro twice. Your compiler could have warned you like

> warning: "abc" redefined  #define abc "rd"

And you simply ignored the warning, which you shouldn't, learn from  warning. For good code practise define the macros under one tag, use `#ifdef`, `#endif` and `#undef`. for e.g

`#ifdef first`

`#define abc 10`

`#endif`

And the define second macro similarly.

Macros got replaced at `preprocessor` stage and it will consider last definition of `abc`.

Finally your code look like

`int main() { printf("%d","rd"); return 0; }`

Now `%d` expects argument of `int` type but you have provided of `"Rd"` i.e `char*` type. So it prints some `garbage` value.

*How can memory be allocated to a macro?* No memory is allocated for macros at runtime at all & these are just a textual replacement.

Answer (score 10):

Macros don't occupy runtime memory at all, they are an entirely compile-time (actually even preprocessing-time) construct. For the most part, you can think of macros as purely textual replacement. So your code is 100% equivalent to this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("%d","rd");
  return 0;
}
```

I believe it's quite clear why this is printing garbage values.

Also, redefining a macro to something else without an intervening `#undef` is actually illegal in C, so the compiler would be justified in rejecting the code altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The second `#define` overrides the first one. so ultimately `abc` is a string literal. Now you are trying to interpret  `abc`  as a integer because you are using `%d` in `printf`.

This is what `printf look like:`printf("%d","rd");` after the pre-processor finishes its job.

Comment: Actually,  if *"the name of a predefined macro, or the identifier defined, is the subject of a #define or #undef preprocessing directive (6.10.8)."*, the behaviour is undefined.